# Paypal Recurring Payments find if payment is dont or not

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

i am integrating paypal recuring payment where Ist month payment is free. and after it is chargebal. my probleam is after making payment profile of user how i find if this month payment is done or not of this particular profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log into your account and view the profile, it will show you the payment history for that profile.  If you are using IPN, you could set up a backend system for recording this information and viewing it.  Every time a payment is completed, you will get an IPN, which you would just have your system write it to the database.